# Django form in an extended template

Tags: python, django, forms

I am very new to Django, I have a home template (home.html) which is extending a base template (base.html) with `{% extends "base.html" %}`.

`base.html` containts a contact form.

```
<form id="email-form" name="email-form" data-name="Email Form" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div>
        <label for="Name-2" class="field-label">Full name</label>
        {% render_field form.name class+="text-field w-input" %}
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="Email-2" class="field-label">Email address</label>
        {% render_field form.from_email class+="text-field _2 w-input" %}
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="Phone-2" class="field-label">Phone number</label>
        {% render_field form.phone class+="text-field _2 w-input" %}
    </div>
    <div>
         <label for="Timeline" class="field-label">More information</label>
         <div>
             {% render_field form.message class+="text-field area w-input" %}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="algin-center form-actions">
        <input type="submit" value="Send Message" data-wait="Please wait..." class="button full w-button">
    </div>
</form>
```

`views.py`

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    from_email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    phone = forms.CharField(required=True)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, required=True)

def homeView(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactForm()
    else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
            from_email = form.cleaned_data['from_email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            try:
                send_mail(name, message, from_email, ['email@email.com'])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('success')
    return render(request, "home.html", {'form': form})
```

The form is rendering fine, however, when I click the submit button nothing happens. I'm guessing this is because the form is not in the homeView directly but through extension, but I have no idea how to fix it, is it possible to have the form in an extended view?

Comment: You did not specify an action in your form.

Comment: Ah, thank you. That does submit the form, however, multiple pages extend this base class, so the form can be submitted from all of them. How could I make it stay on the current page for each one

Comment: You specify as action the url of your `homeView`?